# Deprecated youtube API's

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I read on this page https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list YouTube API Subject to the Deprecation Policy

On this page is the YouTube IFrame Player API.

Does this mean that this api is deprecated ?

Hope someone can shine a light on this page

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that section 7 of the Youtube API terms of service helps clarify things a bit:

> Google will announce if it intends to discontinue or make backwards
>   incompatible changes to this API or Service. Google will use
>   commercially reasonable efforts to continue to operate those YouTube
>   API versions and features identified at
>   http://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list without these
>   changes until the later of: (i) one year after the announcement or
>   (ii) April 20, 2015, unless (as Google determines in its reasonable
>   good faith judgment):
>
> required by law or third party relationship (including if there is a
>   change in applicable law or relationship), or doing so could create a
>   security risk or substantial economic or material technical burden.

So in other words, there's not an announced deprecation of those APIs on the list you pointed to, but they reserve the right to announce deprecations that fall under the policy above. Here are the API technologies that have been officially deprecated:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_deprecated